# Jquery hidden input select to to write value

Tags: jquery

I use Jquery typeahead

In the onClickAfter: function(node, a, item, event) event i do

```
node.closest('td').first('input[type=hidden]').attr('value',item.id);
```

A part of the html code

```
<td>
     <input type="hidden" name="carParams[2].id">
     <input type="hidden" name="carParams[2].idJoins">
     <div class="typeahead__container cancel">
             <div class="typeahead__field">
                 <span class="typeahead__query">
                     <span class="typeahead__cancel-button"></span><input name="carParams[2].name" class="form-control js-typeahead" type="search" placeholder="Type partial value" autocomplete="off">
                 </span>
             </div>
     <div class="typeahead__result"><ul class="typeahead__list"><li class="typeahead__item typeahead__group-carparam"><a href="javascript:;" data-group="carParam" data-index="0"><span class="typeahead__display"><strong>color value</strong></span></a></li></ul></div></div>
</td>
```

Problem is value field is not put a the right place...

```
<td value="45">
```

would like to put it to  `<input type="hidden" name="carParams[2].id">`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/first/ Try `node.closest('td').find('input[type=hidden]').first().attr....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
node.closest('td').find('input[type=hidden]').first().attr('value',item.id);
```

https://api.jquery.com/first/ as stated "Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set."

Your original code does this on the `td` and not `input` which is where the issue is. Also `first()` does not accept any parameters. You can use `.find()` to get the hidden input first and then use `first()` to reduce it to the first one

The solution can be applied to different forms

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find()` to traverse the children

```
node.closest('td').find('input[name="carParams[2].id"]').attr('value',item.id);
```